# Index seek instead of index scan for is not null in condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-indexes

I have the query below...

```sql
SELECT Compra_ID
FROM [Fart_Compras_dss_tracking]
WHERE [local_create_peer_timestamp] IS NOT NULL
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE [DataSync].[Fart_Compras_dss_tracking]
(
    [COMPRA_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Sucursal_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [update_scope_local_id] [int] NULL,
    [scope_update_peer_key] [int] NULL,
    [scope_update_peer_timestamp] [bigint] NULL,
    [local_update_peer_key] [int] NOT NULL,
    [local_update_peer_timestamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [create_scope_local_id] [int] NULL,
    [scope_create_peer_key] [int] NULL,
    [scope_create_peer_timestamp] [bigint] NULL,
    [local_create_peer_key] [int] NOT NULL,
    [local_create_peer_timestamp] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [sync_row_is_tombstone] [int] NOT NULL,
    [last_change_datetime] [datetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_DataSync.Fart_Compras_dss_tracking] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([COMPRA_ID] ASC, [Sucursal_ID] ASC)
                WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Idx_Text_4] 
ON [DataSync].[Fart_Compras_dss_tracking] ([COMPRA_ID] ASC,
                                           [Sucursal_ID] ASC,
                                           [local_create_peer_timestamp] ASC,
                                           [local_update_peer_timestamp] ASC)
INCLUDE ([update_scope_local_id], [scope_update_peer_key],
         [scope_update_peer_timestamp], [local_update_peer_key],
         [create_scope_local_id], [scope_create_peer_key],
         [scope_create_peer_timestamp], [local_create_peer_key],
         [sync_row_is_tombstone], [last_change_datetime]) 
WHERE ([local_create_peer_timestamp] IS NOT NULL)
WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

[image]

Execution plan is available in the link below...

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkZbOe8zi

When  I take a look at the execution plan it shows INDEX SCAN, I tried creating different indexes/filtered indexes, but I am not able to see INDEX SEEK even forcing the usage of my indexes.

What index is required to improve performance for `IS NOT NULL` conditions like this?

Comment: Add the `CREATE INDEX` DDL and query to your question.  Also, upload the actual execution plan XML to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question.

Comment: What is the **structure** of your table? Columns, their datatypes, any indexes etc. ?

Comment: The plan you shared has a different query, has two predicates in the where clause, and shows a clustered index scan for a different table with one row. I don't think there is any benefit to trying to convert _that_ scan to a seek, but maybe you could try again and share the plan we're actually talking about here.

Comment: You don't need to see an index seek here. The benefit the filtered index provides here is that it contains only a subset of table rows. Effectively it has pre-calculated exactly the ones matching the `WHERE [local_create_peer_timestamp] IS NOT NULL` predicate. So scanning that is fine. 100% of them will match the `WHERE` on the query. There is no more selective seek possible

Answer (score 0):

The index you showed us isn't suitable for optimizing your filter condition. (It does seem to be quicker to scan than your PK clustered index, but a scan is still required.)

This index will help performance.

```sql
CREATE INDEX tstamp ON Fart_Compras_dss_tracking 
      (local_create_peer_timestamp);
```

It can be random-accessed by your WHERE filter. You'll still see an index range scan.

Comment: The index they show us is fine for optimising the query. It is a filtered index and only contains the exact entries matching the `[local_create_peer_timestamp] IS NOT NULL)` predicate so scanning that index is fine